# Magento 2 - Adding a design configuration setting issue

Tags: magento2, magento2.1

Apologies if this question has been asked and answered already, or documentation provides a solution, but I can't seem to get my head around this.

My objective is to add a custom field within the design configuration settings, where an administrator can toggle enabling Christmas effects to the frontend store. From what I have read online, the best way to do this is via a custom module, though I may be wrong?

So I have created a module to add a design configuration setting (Set Christmas Theme). In the module's `etc/di.xml` file, I have added the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

  <type name="Magento\Theme\Model\Design\Config\MetadataProvider">
    <arguments>
      <argument name="metadata" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="header_christmas_theme" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="path" xsi:type="string">design/header/christmas_theme</item>
            <item name="fieldset" xsi:type="string">other_settings/header</item>
            <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
        </item>
      </argument>
    </arguments>
  </type>
</config>
```

Within the module's `view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml` file, I have added the following:

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
  <field name="header_christmas_theme">
      <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</item>
          <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Set Christmas Theme</item>
              <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
              <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
              <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
              <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">header_christmas_theme</item>
              <item name="value" xsi:type="string">0</item>
          </item>
      </argument>
  </field>
</form>
```

When enabling the module, running setup:upgrade in console and clearing the cache, I get the error below. Can anyone assist on where I am going wrong with adding a custom field to the design configuration?

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The configuration parameter "componentType" is a required for "header_christmas_theme" component.

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The configuration parameter "componentType" is a required for "header_christmas_theme" component.
#0 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(361): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadataItem(Array, Array, false)
#1 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(361): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadataItem(Array, Array, false)
#2 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(361): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadataItem(Array, Array, false)
#3 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(272): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadataItem(Array, Array, false)
#4 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(164): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadata('design_config_f...', Array, false)
#5 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(124): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create('design_config_f...', NULL, Array)
#6 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(93): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->generateComponent(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure), 'design_config_f...', Array, Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor))
#7 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#8 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(327): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#9 /var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(89): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements()
#10 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(129): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements()
#11 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php(55): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#12 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#13 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(244): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#14 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(859): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build()
#15 /var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(414): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock('menu')
#16 /vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/View/Result/Page.php(59): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getBlock('menu')
#17 /var/generation/Magento/Backend/Model/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page->setActiveMenu('Magento_Theme::...')
#18 /vendor/magento/module-theme/Controller/Adminhtml/Design/Config/Edit.php(69): Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->setActiveMenu('Magento_Theme::...')
#19 /var/generation/Magento/Theme/Controller/Adminhtml/Design/Config/Edit/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Theme\Controller\Adminhtml\Design\Config\Edit->execute()
#20 /vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Magento\Theme\Controller\Adminhtml\Design\Config\Edit\Interceptor->execute()
#21 /vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(226): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Theme\Controller\Adminhtml\Design\Config\Edit\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#24 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Theme\\C...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Theme\Controller\Adminhtml\Design\Config\Edit\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...')
#25 /vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Theme\Controller\Adminhtml\Design\Config\Edit\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Theme\\C...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Theme\Controller\Adminhtml\Design\Config\Edit\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
#28 /vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Magento\Theme\Controller\Adminhtml\Design\Config\Edit\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Theme\Controller\Adminhtml\Design\Config\Edit\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 /var/generation/Magento/Theme/Controller/Adminhtml/Design/Config/Edit/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Theme\Controller\Adminhtml\Design\Config\Edit\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#31 /vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Theme\Controller\Adminhtml\Design\Config\Edit\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#32 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#33 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#34 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#35 /vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#36 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#37 /var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#38 /vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#39 /vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#40 /index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#41 {main}
```

Comment: check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/125482/20064

Answer (score 0):

You should add "header_christmas_theme" into existing fieldset or add new fieldset with a separate name abnd include it into the configuraion xml file

Answer (score 0):

Try this. For me it worked!

remove from di.xml this

```
  <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
```

and in design:config_form.xml add this

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<fieldset name="other_settings" sortOrder="30">
    <fieldset name="header">
        <field name="header_christmas_theme" formElement="select">
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="validate-no-html-tags" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <componentType>field</componentType>
                <label translate="true">Set Christmas Theme</label>
                <dataScope>header_christmas_theme</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</fieldset>
```